# 360 panorama in Browser, HTCVive, Oculus Rift

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, unity-webgl, 360-panorama

can you please help me to understand how can I make 360 panorama for Web.
I am using SteamVR and Oculus sdk because I want universal app for (Web, HTCVive, Oculus Rift).

It works in Unity but after compiling for WebGL it does not work on web.
Please review this [link](http://16bitfamily.com/test/).

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?Or maybe to develop the universal app is impossible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTC Vive or Oculus SDK are meant for platform specific apps. You cannot use them in WebGL build. Unity at the moment doesn't have anything for WebGL + WebVR according to [this](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/webgl-and-webvr.390445/).

But to support both features WebGL and WebVR you can [this plugin](https://github.com/Boondogl/Unity-WebVR-Template). This is a WebGL template which has a wraper of WebVR in its js script.

Follow this link to implement it in your WebGL App : [Exporting An Indie Unity Game to WebVR](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/05/exporting-an-indie-unity-game-to-webvr/)

But I recommend you create platform specific builds as well for Oculus and HTC Vive. Its not much effort to change the platform and build the app.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer will try!

Comment: Mmm sorry, I think this not exactly what I want. As I undesrtand WebGL + WebVR allow me to connect headset to browser right?However, I need a but simplest, something like this  https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web to be able to rotate in browser. Here is a link which they provided https://github.com/googlevr/vrview and I see it is not Unity. Is it possible with Unity?

Comment: So you don't want the VR split screen view like [this](http://ios-s1.infcdn.net/images_ios/screenshots_ios/7/44/dc/2055598_3.jpg) in your webGL build?

Comment: If you are thinking of doing exact same thing as VRView from google but in Unity WebGL to support multiple platforms. You should know that unity webGL is not meant for Oculus or Vive. These devices need to access your WebGL app through a browser. So why use unity to make a web App which can be made using one line native code. As at the end of the day you will be viewing it in a browser.